# Time Limit decorator

Tags: c#, timeout

I have an interface named `ICodeRunner`, defined like this:

```cs
public interface ICodeRunner
{
        ExecutionResult Run(string code);
}
```

I have more classes that implement `ICodeRunner`, but regardless of which one is used, in some contexts only I have to impose a time limit on the execution of the `Run` method. This is a regular timeout: "if it's not done in x seconds, throw an exception."

To achieve this, I have created a class called `CodeRunnerTimeLimitDecorator` that can wrap any class implementing `ICodeRunner` and provide this functionality.

This is how the class is implemented:

```cs
public class CodeRunnerTimeLimitDecorator : ICodeRunner
{
        private readonly ICodeRunner _wrapped;
        private readonly int _timeoutInSeconds;

        public CodeRunnerTimeLimitDecorator(ICodeRunner wrapped, int timeoutInSeconds)
        {
                _wrapped = wrapped;
                _timeoutInSeconds = timeoutInSeconds;
        }

        public ExecutionResult Run(string code)
        {
                var executionResult = new ExecutionResult();

                var t = new Thread(() => executionResult = _wrapped.Run(code));

                t.Start();

                var completed = t.Join(_timeoutInSeconds * 1000);

                if (completed)
                        return executionResult;

                throw new ApplicationException(
                        string.Format("Code took longer than {0} seconds to run, so it was aborted.", _timeoutInSeconds));
        }
}
```

While I welcome any advice about how to make this code better, I'm particularly interested in comments/improvements regarding the time limit mechanism.

**Update:**

More specifically, the questions are:

1. Is there an easier/cleaner way to do it?
2. Would it be OK if I called `t.Abort()` in case the timeout had elapsed*?

**I do not control the process that goes on inside `_wrapped.Run(code)`, so I cannot implement [Task Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx) or similar techniques.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a stab in the dark but could you use the .NET 4 System.Threading.Task object for this.  Something like:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _wrapped.Run(code) });

// Wait returns true if the task finished within the allocated timeframe
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270644.aspx
if(task.Wait(_timeoutInSeconds * 1000))
{
   return executionResult;
}
else
{
   throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Code took longer than {0} seconds to run, so it was aborted.", _timeoutInSeconds));
}
```

Comment: This definitely gains in terms of conciseness and code clarity, so +1! I am also looking for a advice on aborting the thread, in case it has exceeded the timeout.

Comment: @w0lf there is a CancellationToken that can be used with the TPL which has been shown above. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783865/how-do-i-abort-cancel-tpl-tasks

Comment: @TrevorPilley Thanks for this clarification; I just realized I did not properly formulate the question. Please see my edit.

Comment: @w0lf I don't think you should really be either 'newing' up a Thread or calling Thread.Abort(), have a look into ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem instead

Comment: @W0lf ah, my bad. I'll be interested to see what others say!